# Заменить точку с запятой в строке, обрамленной кавычками

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Помогите написать регулярное выражение, которое ищет в строке, обрамленной двойными кавычками, точку с запятой и заменяет точку с запятой на точку.

Comment: Не любят тут такие вопросы. Что у вас сделали сами и что не получилось?

Comment: не получается из подстроки, обрамленной кавычками, убрать точку с запятой. Пробовал так: preg_replace("/^\"(\W);(\W)\"+$/", "$1.$2", $text);

Answer (score 2):

С учетом экранированных кавычек и прочих замечаний выше:

```
$text = <<< EOS
Гибридизация; "ковалентно испаряет \"фрагментарный;\" катионит при любом катализаторе;".
Энергетический подуровень \"синфазно;\" адсорбирует "квазар; тем самым; открывая; возможность;;;;"
синтеза тетрахлордифенилдиоксина;
EOS;
```

.

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/(?<!\\\)".*?(?<!\\\)"/s', 
    function($m) { return str_replace(';', ',', $m[0]); }, $text);

/*
string(395) "Гибридизация; "ковалентно испаряет \"фрагментарный,\" катионит при любом катализаторе,".
Энергетический подуровень \"синфазно;\" адсорбирует "квазар, тем самым, открывая, возможность,,,,"
синтеза тетрахлордифенилдиоксина;"
*/
var_dump($result);
```

Для PHP <5.3 заменить замыкание функцией, вестимо.

**UPD.**
Та же самая регулярка более подробно с комментариями:

```
/            # соответствует выражению, если подвыражение в скобках
    (?<!     # НЕ предшествует символу после скобок
        \\\  # backslash. почему их 3: http://php.net/regexp.reference.escape 
    )
    "        # открывающаяся кавычка

    .*?      # не жадное соответствие любым символам

    (?<!     # то же самое, что и выше
        \\\  # backslash
    )
    "        # закрывающаяся кавычка
/sx
```

Алгоритм простой: регулярное выражение находит все строки в кавычках целиком с учетом экранирования и для их замены применяет callback, который в свою очередь заменяет в строке все символы `;`  на `,`.

**UPD 2.**

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), нет, не так. `(?<! )` - это предикат, который не захватывает никакие символы, а лишь добавляет дополнительное условие для сопоставления следующего за ним символа. В `pcre` есть и другие виды условных предикатов:

- `(?= )`  - истинно если подвыражение в скобках следует после предшествующего символа
- `(?! )`  - истинно если подвыражение в скобках НЕ следует после предшествующего символа
- `(?<= )` - истинно если подвыражение в скобках предшествует следующему символу
- `(?<! )` - истинно если подвыражение в скобках НЕ предшествует следующему символу

Т.о. если кавычка будет в начале строки, то данное условие будет истинно (поскольку начало строки не соответствует обратному слешу) и кавычка захватиться.

> Еще (если я правилно понял) почему между кавычками д.б. как минимум 2 символа ?
>
> `?(?<!\\\)"`
>
> Это ведь часть для поиска "завершающей" кавычки ?

Нет, я специально разбил составляющие шаблона на строки.

`?`, стоящий после квантификатора, является инвертором жадности соответствующего квантификатора. Т.е. выражение `.*?` эквивалентно `.*` стой-лишь разницей, что первое не жадное (или наоборот первое жадное, а второе не жадное, если используется глобальный модификатор жадности)

А завершающая кавычка задается так-же как и открывающая.

Comment: Подсветка глючит.

Comment: Круто !

Еще бы понять **как** это работает.

Comment: А разве в php есть поддержка негативного локахеада? `(?<!...)` .  
 Буквально недавно пробовал сделать такую регулярку- движок ругался.  
А вообще надо учитывать, что перед экранированной кавычкой может быть сколько угодно экранированных слэшей. То есть примерно так надо делать.  

    (?<!(\\\\)*\\)

Comment: Обновил ответ.

> А разве в php есть поддержка негативного локахеада?

Да, PCRE в PHP всегда поддерживал и условия и рекурсивные выражения.

> `(?<!(\\\\)*\\)`

Это не будет работать, поскольку условие не может содержать квантификаторы, оно может быть только фиксированной длины.

Comment: Ага. Верно. Я уже тоже протестил и столкнулся с этой ошибкой, раньше не знал об этой особенности `?<!`

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, если я правильно понял

    (?<!\\\)"

это *любой символ и неэкранированная кавычка* ?

Тогда я не понимаю, что будет, если **вся** строка начинается с кавычки ?

Еще (если я правилно понял) почему между кавычками д.б. как минимум 2 символа ?

    ?(?<!\\\)"

Это ведь часть для поиска "завершающей" кавычки ?

Или я неправильно разобрался в Вашем пояснении ?

Comment: @avp, обновил ответ, а то в комментарий не влезло.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, спасибо за пояснениния. 

Реально понял, что этот замечательно мощный инструмент приведет в средних руках к огромному числу полуработающих (и реально всегда недоотлаженных) программ.

На самом деле слишком сложно (или слишком кратко, чтобы быть понятным).

Comment: @avp, разумеется, эта фраза применима ко многим технологиям, например, к тому же `C`.

Однако, все же трудно недооценить насколько *огромное* количество времени способны сэкономить регулярные выражения в умелых руках. Причем это относится не только к продакшену, но и к разработке (трудно представить себе рефакторинг без grep), и к администрированию (быстро проанализировать любой лог, например), и прочим повседневным проблемам.

Comment: Спасибо. Понятно.

Кстати, *тетрахлордифенилдиоксин* в Вашем примере весьма символично.

Answer (score 1):

Извините, за уже наверно некропостную правку.
Скорее всего это окончательная версия регулярного выражения, потому что опробовал все возможные варианты экранирования и совместного размещения участвующих в регулярном выражении частей- все разбирается как надо.

```
<? header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8;");
$re='/((((?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)*)|[^\\\\;])")(.*?)((((?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)*)|[^\\\\])")/';
$s= <<< HEREDOC
"; кавычка в начале текста и точка с запятой (ТЗ) сразу после нее"
\\" экранированные слэши в начале и конце; \\" экранированные кавычки внутри \\\\" ; \\\\\\" ;  \\\\\\\\"
\\" ; \\\\\\" ; \\\\\\\\\\" ; экранированные кавычки вне
";;" ТЗ сразу после и сразу перед кавычкой
;;"";; пустая строка в кавычках ТЗ до и после кавычек
\\\\" кавычка; в ;конце ;текста"
HEREDOC;
function clb($match){
    return str_replace(";", ".", $match[0]);
};
echo '<pre>'.preg_replace_callback($re, clb, $s)."</pre>"; ?>
```

Результат

```
". кавычка в начале текста и точка с запятой (ТЗ) сразу после нее"
\" экранированные слэши в начале и конце; \" экранированные кавычки внутри \\" . \\\" .  \\\\"
\" ; \\\" ; \\\\\" ; экранированные кавычки вне
".." ТЗ сразу после и сразу перед кавычкой
;;"";; пустая строка в кавычках ТЗ до и после кавычек
\\" кавычка. в .конце .текста"
```

Comment: Вощемта адовый трэш и дикий угар например

Comment: Тут много лишних отладочных скобок, а вообще оно проще, чем кажется.

Comment: @ReinRaus, а проверьте 

    ";"";";dfcz"5555;5;\";55;5;\\;";6;6\";dv\\"dddf;"df

IMHO должно быть

    "."".";dfcz"5555.5.\".55.5.\\.";6;6\";dv\\"dddf."df

Comment: @avp, а Вы привели чистую строку или ее запись в php?  
Чистая строка проходит замену корректно, как у Вас в результате.  

    $a=' ";"";";dfcz"5555;5;\";55;5;\\;";6;6\";dv\\"dddf;"df';
    echo $a;
    // ";"";";dfcz"5555;5;\";55;5;\;";6;6\";dv\"dddf;"df
Чтобы получилась такая чистая строка надо  

    $a=' ";"";";dfcz"5555;5;\\";55;5;\\\\;";6;6\\";dv\\\\"dddf;"df';

Comment: По моему, проверять все слеши - это уже перебор. Максимум можно проверить экранирование первого слеша.


    $text = <<< 'EOS'
    ";"";";dfcz"5555;5;\";55;5;\\;";6;6\";dv\\"dddf;"df
    EOS;

.
    
    $pattern = <<< 'EOS'
    /(?<!(?<!\\)\\)".*?(?<!(?<!\\)\\)"/s
    EOS;

.
   
    $result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) {return str_replace(';', '.', $m[0]);}, $text);
    
    // ","",";dfcz"5555,5,\",55,5,\\,";6;6\";dv\\"dddf,"df
    echo $result;

> Чтобы получилась такая чистая строка надо

В принципе, можно просто через HEREDOC записать.

Comment: `(?<!(?<!\\)\\)"`  
Это кавычка перед которой нет слэша, перед которым нет слэша.  
Непонятно.  
Не знаю насколько излишне проверять все варианты экранирования, но так решается общий случай, а не частный, что лучше наверно.

Comment: @RainRaus, я так и не понял (после Ваших 'чистая строка' (что это ?)), что получилось. Вот, если в Вашем примере написать:

    $s='";"";";dfcz"5555;5;\";55;5;\\;";6;6\";dv\\"dddf;"df';

т.е. **строка начинается с кавычки**, то что получается ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "hello ; world";
str_replace(";", ".", $str); // hello . world
```

Comment: Неверно вопрос поставил по-ходу. Мне не нужно все точки с запятой из строки убрать, а только те точки с запятой, которые находятся в подстроке, обрамленной кавычками. Тут регулярка нужна. За ответ спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace('/"([^"]*);([^"]*)"/', '"$1.$2"', $str);
```

Т.е.

```
кавычка
(все что не кавычка, 0+ символов - $1)
;
(все что не кавычка, 0+ символов - $2)
кавычка
```

меняем на

```
кавычка
$1
точка
$2
кавычка
```

Comment: Если подходить серьезно, то есть нерешенная 
проблема в кавычках внутри кавычек, которые обычно экранируют. 

Т.е. кавычка в паре символов \\" не должна восприниматься, как завершающая кавычка.

IMHO регулярками это не решается.

Но, решать автору вопроса.

И еще, IMHO у Вас в выражении "а;и;с" **вторая ; не заменится**.

Comment: @avp, да, про экранирование я промолчал - ибо нужна регулярка. Собственно, пункт 2 туда же - я не слышал про циклические паттерны, а если в регулярке и можно сделать `/"([^"]*)(;[^"]*)*"/` то в замену вставить все равно не получится.

Comment: Да, к сожалению для многих практических задач регулярки сначала представляются весьма соблазнительными, а потом не срабатывают. 

Плохо, если это выясняется в ходе эксплуатации, на данных заказчика.

Comment: @avp, я решил регулярками :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, вижу, отметил. 

Интересно, сколько времени ушло на все с тестированием-отладкой ?

А теперь представьте, что в это чудо надо еще что-нибудь добавить.

Comment: Минут 10, правда я пока работу работал обдумывал эту регулярку в голове, так что в сумме 10 минут практики и час раздумий без компьютера :)